# How to unpivot a collection/array with Lodash.js?

Tags: javascript, lodash, unpivot

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, and I would like to unpivot a collection/array.

I have a collection/array like this :

```js
[
  { 'produit': 'a', 'color': 'white', 'material': 'leather' }, 
  { 'produit': 'b', 'attribute': 'black', 'material': 'wool' }
]
```

and I would like to transform my collection/array to get something like this :

```js
var a = [
  { 'produit': 'a', 'attribute': 'color', 'value': 'white' }, 
  { 'produit': 'a', 'attribute': 'material', 'value': 'leather' }, 
  { 'produit': 'b', 'attribute': 'color', 'value' :'black' },
  { 'produit': 'b', 'attribute': 'material', 'value': 'wool' }
]
```

I try to find something in the documentation of lodash.js, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#flatMap), by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `produit` key for each object and then [mapping](https://lodash.com/docs/#map) the [keys/values](https://lodash.com/docs/#toPairs) of the remaining object to a new object which includes the `produit` key, the key as the `attribute` key and the value as the `value` key:

```js
const arr = [
  { 'produit': 'a', 'color': 'white', 'material': 'leather' }, 
  { 'produit': 'b', 'attribute': 'black', 'material': 'wool' }
];

const res = _.flatMap(
  arr,
  ({produit, ...r}) => _.map(_.entries(r), ([attribute, value]) => ({produit, attribute, value}))
);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

JS has many inbuilt array functions these days, so the above can also be achieved in vanilla JS using similar methods:

```js
const arr = [
  { 'produit': 'a', 'color': 'white', 'material': 'leather' }, 
  { 'produit': 'b', 'attribute': 'black', 'material': 'wool' }
];

const res = arr.flatMap(
  ({produit, ...r}) => Object.entries(r).map(([attribute, value]) => ({produit, attribute, value}))
);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need lodash for this. You can easily do this using object destruction and reduction.

```js
const original = [
  { 'produit': 'a', 'color': 'white', 'material': 'leather' }, 
  { 'produit': 'b', 'attribute': 'black', 'material': 'wool' }
]

const altered = original.reduce((acc, item) =>
  (({ produit, ...rest }) =>
    Object.entries(rest).reduce((result, [attribute, value]) =>
      [ ...result, { produit, attribute, value } ], acc))(item), []);

console.log(altered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```